# Advanced REST client's new update, No session

Tags: session, advanced-rest-client

I've been using Advanced Rest client to test my REST api. Earlier Advanced Rest client used to open as a new tab in chrome. So I could Login into my application in one browser tab and in a new tab I could open Advanced Rest client, call my api's.. test it. Everything was ok.

But now after the new update Advanced Rest client has become a separate app, I can no longer open it in a new tab. So now I when I call my rest api's, I'm getting No session.

How do I add session in the new update of Rest client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to install this extension (ARC cookie exchange): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-cookie-exchange/apcedakaoficjlofohhcmkkljehnmebp

and enable the Use XHR toggle in the Advanced rest client. It should then work.

Comment: Thank you. I've been copying the JSession id all this time.

Comment: Thanks! Raghavan for president!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a session type. If this is a cookies based session the app is already supports cookies. They are saved in local database (as user agents would do) and automatically added to the request when the domain and path of the cookie matches the request URL. (domain and path matching algorithm is defined in the spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3).

The app will not accept cookies set in regular Chrome session since Chrome apps do not have access to the Chrome's cookie storage. There's simply no API for this. So session registration must be done in app - not the browser. So if the session is set up after form submission you need to create the request that will send form data as regular form would do and then use the app normally.